# Get Channel ID from an Activity using YouTube Data API

Tags: vb.net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the YouTube Data API and I have tried to puzzle out many thing to get to this stage and so far I have done it.

I have come across an issue though. I need to be able to get the ID of the channel to which the activity is related to or the channel that posted a specific video. I need this so I can get channel art such as the avatar and banner.

I am using the

```
    Google.YouTube.Activity
```

class for this.

Comment: How does one get a -1 for asking a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out after 3 hours of attempting things. Eventually I looked at the raw data YouTube returned and found a way.

```
Dim settings As New YouTubeRequestSettings("Application Name", "Developer/API Key")
Dim request As New YouTubeRequest(settings)

For Each activity As Google.YouTube.Activity In request.GetActivities().Entries
     Dim channelId As String = activity.AtomEntry.Authors(0).Uri.Content.Split("/")(6)
Next
```

Hopefully the above code is pretty self explanatory.